# js.erb passing parameters wrongly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have this link which fires mine "show_replies" method in "tweets" controller

```
  <% @replies_link = link_to "show replies", tweets_show_replies_path(:parent => tweet, active: false ), method: :post, remote: true, class: "show-replies" %>
```

as you can see it has two parameters **parent** and **active** and it's rendered as this

```
<a class="show-replies" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/tweets/show_replies?active=false&parent=1">show replies</a>
```

**show_replies** method looks like this

```
def show_replies

    @active_param = params[:active]
    @parent = Tweet.find(params[:parent])
    @tweet = Tweet.new

    if @active_param === true
        params[:active] = false
    else
        params[:active] = true
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {render :nothing => true}
        format.js
    end

end
```

and this is my **show_replies.js.erb**

```
var parent_tweet = $('#tweet-<%= @parent.id %>');
$(parent_tweet).find('.replies').append(' <%=j render "tweets/replies" %> ');
$(parent_tweet).find('.show-replies').attr('href', "<%=j tweets_show_replies_path(:parent => @parent, active: params[:active]) %>")
```

but after changing **href** attribute with my show_replies.js.erb the parameters in the link are just in wrong format which is this

```
<a class="show-replies active" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/tweets/show_replies?active=true&amp;parent=1">show replies</a>
```

do you know why the js script added "amp;" to my attributes url? Is there a way how to fix it? Because when I click on the link second tyme my "show_replies" method can't read the parameters properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails, unsafe values are automatically escaped. `&` is considered as an unsafe value, so it gets escaped to `&amp;`.

But I think a generated link should not be escaped, should be used as is I mean. So I think you should use the raw output in here with :

```
 <%== tweets_show_replies_path(:parent => @parent, active: params[:active]) %>
```

or :

```
 <%= raw tweets_show_replies_path(:parent => @parent, active: params[:active]) %>
```

Comment: Wrong approach in my opinion, but only for the generated link.

Comment: could you please tell me what would be better approach in your oppinion?

Comment: It's okay to render the generated link as raw. But you should escape rest of the js code rendered.